# Print every number in a table that is greater than all the numbers in its right

Tags: algorithm

I have to build an algorithm that prints every number from a table that is greater than all the numbers in its right. Example A={93,24,57,29,41}. 93,57,41 should be printed. Here is what I did:

```
Algorithm leader(A[0:n-1],n)

k=0;
for i=0 to n-2 do
{ for j=i+1 to n-1 do
{  if A[i]>A[j]
    then {k=k+1;
          B[k]=A[i];}}
k=k+1
B[k]=A[n-1] //Adds the last number of the table.
return B;
```

Comment: What if walk goes from right to left?

Comment: @MBo it can be that way too but I want to know if this is right

Comment: No, you put the number into the result array when it is greater than ANY of the numbers to the right. You should count the numbers less than A[i] instead and only after the inner iteration (j) you should push it into the result array (B) if the counted numbers matches the numbers checked (n - 1 - i).

Answer (score 0):

Your implementation is wrong. To properly implement your  approach, you need to check whether current left item is greater all the rest at right. Possible pseudocode:

```
for i=0 to n-1 do
  j = i + 1
  while (j < n) and (A[j] < A[i])
     j++
  if j == n  //we did not meet greater element
      output A[i]

  //possible optimization - jump to the next candidate
  //else
  //   i = j
```

Answer (score -1):

Hmm I'd suggest you to go backwards and to save the largest number you meet.

Hence you will check your current number with the largest if it is greater than this then it should be printed and it should be your largest. If it is not it's not bigger than all of the numbers on the right. :)

**Edit**

No your solution won't work. In your example the result would be: 93,93,93,93,57,57,41 since you will continue to check if the number A[i] is bigger than A[j] and adding it again and again. You can prevent this by doing something like:

```
for i=0 to n-2 do{ 
    for j=i+1 to n-1 do{  
        if A[i]<A[j] then {
            <boolean flag = false>
        }
    }
if <boolean flag> then {
    k=k+1;
    B[k]=A[i];
    }
}

k=k+1
B[k]=A[n-1]
```

**Note**
I've changed the sign of your check from > to <. Also you are missing '}' on your first for loop.

Comment: I completely understood what u said and it would be more efficient to do it just like u explained, but I need to know about this idea I wrote is it correct or not?

Comment: @Albanian Here I've explained what would be the result and if it would be executed. Just from curiosity if you only needed to know if it would work or not why not just execute it ??